# Can win10 pro/enterprise support 8 nvidia gpus?

Tags: windows-10, gpu

I have a server Supermicro 4028GR-TR. The server supports 8 nvidia gpus. I plugged in all 8 gtx 1070 cards and tried to install win 10 pro and enterprise. The newest nvidia drivers (8.0) from nvidia website was also installed. However in the device management of windows, I can only see 4 monitor adaptor. Also I tried to use CUDA API to retrieve the number of gpus. Unfortunately, the cudaGetDeviceCount function told me there was only 4 GPUs. My question is that does win10 supports 8 GPUs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win10 does not have GPUs limit.
hardware, resources, drivers may limit the GPUs.
on a single CPU motherboard you can have maximum four Quadro/GTX GPUs.

Comment: That may be the problem? I only used one CPU in the mother board which supports two CPUs.